# I need to import issues from HP Quality Center to JIRA

Tags: jira, hp-quality-center

I was using HP Quality Center previously to log the issues. But now I am using JIRA for almost 5 projects. Its data is so important to us. How can I move all the issues from QC to JIRA? I found [this](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/hpsync-plugin.xml) but no idea is it safe to do the import operation? I just posted the question so that if anyone else has already used it, he can tell me.

I heard about [Orasi](http://www.orasi.com/testing-solutions/Pages/JIRA_Bridge.aspx) as well but its not free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no free way to do that, but you can try JAM plugins and you can map each value from JIRA to HP ALM. I have done it for all my prjects. It syncs in almost real time.

Answer (score 0):

JIRA Bridge for HP Quality Center is available for JIRA 4.0 to 5.2.11. So, unless you install an old 5.2.11 version, import your issues, then upgrade JIRA, you should find another way.

My advice : try JIRA Importers Plugin (JIM), it's free.
I already used JIM (I imported issues from Starteam), with csv-exported data.
I didn't success at the first try (iso-latin encoding problems and disturbing ";" chars), but finally it worked quite well.
Don't forget to save the JIM configuration file : you will spare time... ;-)